Is it possible for the feasible regions of an LP problem and its dual to both be compact?
I'm sure this is easy for experts, but I'm not sure how to see it myself and I can't find an answer in any of the references I skimmed through.
We know that if a (maximizing) linear program is feasible, then any value in the feasible region gives a lower bound on the (minimizing) dual program. In particular, feasibility for the principal program is the same thing as bounded-below-ness of the dual program.
My question is whether the feasible region of the dual program can also be bounded above.
More precisely: Is it possible for the feasible region of a linear program and the feasible region of its dual to both be compact?
Here's an overly simple example that shows my point: Consider the LP "maximize $2x+3y$ subject to $x,y \geq 0$, $4x+8y \leq 12$, and $2x+y \leq 3$". Then the principal program has a compact feasible region, while the dual program has a noncompact (though still necessarily bounded below!) feasible region. See the following diagrams (feasible regions are shaded in gray, and constraining hyperplanes are showed in color):
 
So then, is it possible for both regions to be compact? I would also be interested to hear what happens for more general convex optimization problems.
Thanks!

Consider a primal problem $P$, written in standard form as:
$$\matrix{ \text{maximize} & c^T x\cr
   \text{subject to} & A x \le b\cr
                     & x \ge 0\cr} $$
and the corresponding dual problem $D$:
$$ \matrix{ \text{minimize} & b^T y\cr
\text{subject to} & A^T y \ge c\cr
                  & y \ge 0\cr} $$
The empty set is compact, and it is possible for the feasible regions of both $P$ and $D$ to be empty.  But that is the only way both can be compact.
By the strong duality theorem, if the feasible region of $P$ is empty and that of $D$ is not, then $D$ must be unbounded, and similarly with $P$ and $D$ reversed.
Now suppose the feasible regions of both $P$ and $D$ are nonempty.
If the feasible region of $P$ is compact, we could decrease one of the
entries of $b$, i.e. the right side of one of the constraints of $P$,
so that all of the vertices that are feasible for $P$ violate this constraint.
Changing $b$ does not change the feasible region for $D$, so the new problem is still feasible, but the new version of $D$ would then have to be unbounded.  But that means the feasible region of $D$ must be unbounded.
A similar argument shows that if the feasible region of $D$ is compact and that of $P$ is nonempty, the feasible region of $P$ must be unbounded.
